# How can I subscribe to English Learners newsletter?

Tags: support

I don't see an item on the http://stackexchange.com/newsletters page to subscribe to the newsletter.

I am subscribed to several stack exchange newsletters and find it quite useful, so I wish to receive a newsletter each week for this site too. Is it a trait of any fresh open beta stack exchange site (a lack of newsletters) and if so, when will there be such opportunity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to find it in one of three ways:

- type `ell` into the search box at the top;
- type `english language learners` into the search box at the top; or
- click "show 11 more Culture sites..." at the bottom of the Culture box.  After clicking, it appears fifth in the list for me.

Here's what it looks like for me:

> [image: Illustration of typing ell into the search box]

Comment: thanks, I have subscribed already (: The time I asked, there wasn't such newsletter, but it's there now. Probably the hassle was caused by its pre-beta (or what it was anyway) status.

Answer (score 4):

There are beta sites with a newsletter, such as [Russian Language and Usage](https://russian.stackexchange.com/), but they are in beta phase more than ELL. I think it's just a matter of being more days in public beta, or having more visitors per day.